# SSL certicficate for doman and subdomain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I  have to enable ssl for the domain like www.domain.com and subdomain like www.subdomain.domain.com , should i get a wildcard ssl or ssl with 5 different sites?

Comment: Keep in mind that wildcards typically do not work for multiple levels.  so *.domain.com will match www.domain.com and foo.domain.com, but fail for  www.foo.domain.com.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on a number of factors:

- Will you be adding new subdomains?
  *If so a wildcard cert may be for you...*
- Is it important that each site be secured separately?
  (e.g. compromising the cert for one site shouldn't compromise all of them)
  *If so you don't want a wildcard certificate - you want a separate cert for each subdomain*
- Do you need an Extended Validation (EV) Certificate?
  *I don't believe any SSL providers offer wildcard EV certs...*

Comment: You can't get a EV wildcard.... :)

Comment: @Jacob that's what I thought - something about it being verboten because of the validation process.

Comment: Thanks i guess i don't need wildcard certificate . I could get with a ssl for 5 sites.

Comment: @Aditya wildcard or SubjectAlternativeNames both have the same level of security (see my clarification above).  If you're going with 5-names-on-one-cert you may as well go wildcard if you don't need EV. As others mentioned it can make management easier...

Comment: I suggest just going wildcard as it will cost 5K plus a year for 5 EV certs.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard usually costs more, however can be deployed to multiple servers thus eliminating certification renew process for every certificate used. By eliminating I mean, removing the entire process of renewing certificate at the CA. I'm personally vote for the wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Wildcard SSL certificate.  It is easier to manage and renew.